# Overriding CSS on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Twitter Bootstrap Plugin from Worpit for Wordpress, and it adds http://www.drtimkinsella.com/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-v2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css to the head before all other styles. I need to remove the -20px from the row div. I cannot find the css to edit I I cannot over-write the style. I am new to Wordpress, so I really only need find out where to edit those files. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just overwrite the style?

Comment: I keep trying up it aleays gets overwritten by the orignal stylesheet

Comment: Do you have access to the file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to hook up your editor?

Go to Appearance > Editor

Do the following to whichever CSS file which is able to reflect in your site.

```
.row{margin-left:0px !important;*zoom:1;}
```